# How to print a two-dimensional matrix clockwise?

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

I want to print a two-dimensional `N x M` matrix clockwise, for example: suppose the input matrix is

```
 1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

then the output would looks like this:

```
1 2 3 4 8 12 16 15 14 13 9 5 6 7 11 10
```

Here is my implementation in C++:

```
#include <cstdio>    

void circle_print(int a[][4], int lx, int ly, int rx, int ry)
{
    if (lx > rx || ly > ry)
        return;    

    int x = lx, y = ly;    

    for (; y < ry; y++) 
        printf("%d\n", a[x][y]);

    for (; x < rx; x++)
        printf("%d\n", a[x][y]);    

    for (; y > ly; y--)
        printf("%d\n", a[x][y]);    

    for (; x > lx; x--)
        printf("%d\n", a[x][y]);    

    circle_print(a, lx + 1, ly + 1, rx - 1, ry - 1);
}    


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int a[][4] = {
        { 1,  2,  3,  4},
        { 5,  6,  7,  8},
        { 9, 10, 11, 12},
        {13, 14, 15, 16},
        {17, 18, 19, 20},
        {21, 22, 23, 24},
    };    

    circle_print(a, 0, 0, 5, 3);    

    return 0;
}
```

In situation `N > 1`, the result is good. However, when `N = 1`, i.e. the matrix `a` is just `{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }`, the output is `1 2 3 4 3 2` and it's explicitly not expected.

How to modify my code in some elegant ways so that it can fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

A bit different approach without four cycles and recursion, but with `O(n*m)` additional memory. I think it's less error-prone.

```
void circle_print(const vector<vector<int>>& a)
{
    const int step[4][2] = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}, {-1, 0}};
    int dir = 0;
    int n = a.size();
    int m = a[0].size();

    vector<vector<int>> was(n, vector<int>(m, 0));

    int x = 0, y = 0;   
    for (int i = 0; i < n*m; ++i) {
        printf("%d ", a[x][y]);
        was[x][y] = 1;

        int newx = x + step[dir][0];
        int newy = y + step[dir][1];
        if (newx < 0 || newy < 0 || newx == n || newy == m || was[newx][newy] == 1) {
            dir = (dir + 1) % 4;
        } 

        x += step[dir][0];
        y += step[dir][1];
    }
}    


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    vector<vector<int>> a = {
        { 1,  2,  3,  4},
        { 5,  6,  7,  8},
        { 9, 10, 11, 12},
        {13, 14, 15, 16},
        {17, 18, 19, 20},
        {21, 22, 23, 24},
    };    

    circle_print(a);    

    return 0;
}
```

runnable version: http://ideone.com/Qq9VYf

Answer (score 0):

Call `circle_print(a, 0, 0, N, M)` instead of `circle_print(a, 0, 0, N - 1, M - 1)`, but after each `for` loop adjust the index. For instance after `y++` loop do `y = ry - 1`, and after `x--` loop do `x = lx`. Also must adjust the starting value of the index of the each loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the understanding behind how it should be done.

1. Set another matrix of the same size,i.e, M x N. This is to check the the visited cells of the matrix, i.e, 1 if its visited, else 0. Then initialize it as `visited[M][N]={0}`
2. Now make a  recursive function to go to all these paths, for printing

For direction clockwise, the logic can be : First check for going to the right side. If right side doesn't exist, try to go down, if can't go right and down, go left...else go up.

For example : a. First you check for right, and if free, keep going, then when end of matrix, you can't go right.  `So you have 1 2 3 4`
b. Hence go one cell down. Now in this cell, you check for right again. But you can't go again. Thus go down till end of matrix. `You get 4 8 12 16`
c. Now it checks for right, since it can't go; check for down, here also can't go. Then go left. Now when you're in this cell, i.e, `15` , you check for right again. Space is available but cell is already visited so can't go.

The function is as follows:

```
int visited[M][N] ={0);

void printmatrix(int matrix[M][N] , int temp_M, int temp_N)
{ 

//Go Right
 if(temp_M+1 < M && visited[temp_M + 1] !=1 )
 {
   visited[temp_M + 1] = 1; //Marking the cell as visited
   cout<<matrix[temp_M+1][temp_N]<<" ";

   printmatrix(matrix,temp_M+1, temp_N);
 }

//gO Down ,i.e, temp_N+1
else if {..}
//gO LEFT ,i.e, temp_M-1
else if {..}
//gO UP ,i.e, temp_N-1
else if {..}

return;
}

int main()
{..
.
.
printmatrix(matrix,0,0);

return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code fixed:

I got rid of the index values passing on to another loops form the previous ones - it was difficult to reason about and added 2 ifs to cover special cases of single row/column input.

```
#include <cstdio>    

void circle_print(int a[][4], int lx, int ly, int rx, int ry)
{
    if (lx > rx || ly > ry)
        return;    

    for (int y = ly; y <= ry; y++) 
        printf("%d ", a[lx][y]);

    for (int x = lx+1; x <= rx; x++)
        printf("%d ", a[x][ry]);

    if(rx>lx){
    for (int y=ry-1; y >= ly; y--)
        printf("%d ", a[rx][y]);
    }

    if(ry>ly){
    for (int x=rx-1; x > lx; x--)
        printf("%d ", a[x][ly]);
    }

    circle_print(a, lx + 1, ly + 1, rx - 1, ry - 1);
}    


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int a[][4] = {
        { 1,  2,  3,  4},
        { 5,  6,  7,  8},
        { 9, 10, 11, 12},
        {13, 14, 15, 16},
        {17, 18, 19, 20},
        {21, 22, 23, 24},
    };    

    circle_print(a, 0, 0, 5, 3);    

    return 0;
}
```

[Ideone version](https://ideone.com/SuDLYk)

Answer (score 0):

you can simply modify your code as:

```
for (; y > ly && x > lx; y--)
    printf("%d\n", a[x][y]);
```

you should traverse in the reverse, only if you have moved in the vertical direction.

Answer (score 0):

C++ example of clockWiseCout(), for both 2d-array and 1d-std::vector

I implemented 2d-array 1st, then the 1d-std::vector -- intentionally keeping them similar.

This solution is iterative, in one loop and 4 if-clauses

```
#include <chrono>
// 'compressed' chrono access --------------vvvvvvv
typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock  HRClk_t; // std-chrono-hi-res-clk
typedef HRClk_t::time_point                 Time_t;  // std-chrono-hi-res-clk-time-point
typedef std::chrono::microseconds           MS_t;    // std-chrono-milliseconds
typedef std::chrono::microseconds           US_t;    // std-chrono-microseconds
typedef std::chrono::nanoseconds            NS_t;    // std-chrono-nanoseconds
using   namespace std::chrono_literals;          // support suffixes like 100ms, 2s, 30us

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>


class T496_t
{
   typedef std::vector<int> IntVec_t;
   bool dbg = false;

public:

   T496_t() = default;

   ~T496_t() = default;

   //  input:
   //  1  2  3  4
   //  5  6  7  8
   //  9 10 11 12
   // 13 14 15 16

   //  output
   //  1 2 3 4 8 12 16 15 14 13 9 5 6 7 11 10

   int exec()
      {
         // using 2-d array
         {
            int m_4x4[4][4];

            std::cout << "\n\n  Demo using int m_4x4[4][4]\n";
            fill(m_4x4);
            show(m_4x4);
            clockWiseCout(m_4x4);
         }

         // using std::vector() (1-d) and
         {
            IntVec_t m_16x1;

            std::cout << "\n\n  Demo using IntVec_t m_16x1\n";
            fill(m_16x1);
            show(m_16x1);
            clockWiseCout(m_16x1);
         }
         return(0);
      }

private: // methods

   void fill(int m_4x4[][4])
      {
         int val = 1;
         for (int r=0; r<4; ++r)
            for (int c=0; c<4; ++c)
               m_4x4[r][c] = val++;
      }

   void show(int m_4x4[][4])
      {
         std::cout << "\n  void show(int m_4x4[][4]) \n";
         for (int r=0; r<4; ++r) {
            for (int c=0; c<4; ++c) {
               std::cout << std::setw(4) << m_4x4[r][c];
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
         }
         std::cout << std::endl;
      }

   void clockWiseCout(int m_4x4[][4])
      {
         std::cout << "  void clockWiseCout(int m_4x4[][4]) \n  ";
         enum CWCout_Constraints : int {
            right = 1, noHorizontal = 0, left = -1,
            down  = 1, noVertical   = 0, up   = -1
         };

         // limits
         int minR =  0; // stop at 0 after 1 clockwise rotation
         int minC = -1; // stop at 0 - 1
         int maxR =  4; // stop at 3 + 1
         int maxC =  4; // stop at 3 + 1

         // focus
         int rr   = 0; // start upper left corner
         int cc   = 0;

         // start direction, top row, left col
         int rightOrLeft = right;       // horizontal  1, 0, -1
         int upOrDown    = noVertical;  // vertical    1, 0, -1

         // how many
         int count     = 4 * 4;

         do {
            // report current spot
            if(dbg) std::cout << "[" << rr << "][" << cc << "] ";
            std::cout << std::setw(2) << m_4x4[rr][cc] 
                      << "  " << std::flush;

            count -= 1;
            if(dbg) if(0 == (count % 8)) std::cout  << "\n  ";

            // move focus to next spot
            cc += rightOrLeft;  rr += upOrDown;

            if((maxC == cc) && (right == rightOrLeft))
            {
               // right edge -> traveling right
               cc         -= rightOrLeft;    // back 1
               rightOrLeft = noHorizontal;   // no Horizontal move
               upOrDown    = down;           // down
               rr         += upOrDown;       // step
               maxC       -= 1;        // right edge completes, so back 1
            }
            else
               if((minC == cc) && (left == rightOrLeft))
               {
                  // left edge <- traveling left
                  cc         -= rightOrLeft;     // back 1
                  rightOrLeft = noHorizontal;    // stop Horizontal move
                  upOrDown    = up;              // up
                  rr         += upOrDown;        // step up
                  minC       += 1;     // left edge complete, so forward 1
               }
               else
                  if((maxR == rr) && (down == upOrDown))
                  {
                     // bottom -v traveling down
                     rr          -= upOrDown;      // back 1
                     upOrDown     = noVertical;    // stop vertical move
                     rightOrLeft  = left;          // left
                     cc          += rightOrLeft;   // step left
                     maxR        -= 1;     // bottom edge complete, back 1
                  }
                  else
                     if((minR == rr) && (up == upOrDown))
                     {
                        // top -^ traveling up
                        rr         -= upOrDown;     // back 1
                        upOrDown    = noVertical;   // stop vertical
                        rightOrLeft = right;        // right
                        cc         += rightOrLeft;  // step right
                        minR       += 1;            // top edge complete
                     }

         } while(count > 0);
         std::cout << std::endl;

      } // void clockWiseCout()



   // convert 2-d index to 1-d index
   size_t vecIndx(int r, int c) { return ((r * 4) + c); }

   void fill(IntVec_t& m_16x1)
      {
         m_16x1.reserve(16); // allocate space
         int val = 1;
         for (int r=0; r<4; ++r)
            for (int c=0; c<4; ++c)
               m_16x1[vecIndx(r,c)] = val++;
      }

   void show(IntVec_t& m_16x1)
      {
         std::cout << "\n  void show(IntVec_t& m_16x1) \n";
         for (int r=0; r<4; ++r) {
            for (int c=0; c<4; ++c) {
               std::cout << std::setw(4) << m_16x1[vecIndx(r,c)];
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
         }
         std::cout << std::endl;
      }


   void clockWiseCout(IntVec_t& m_16x1)
      {
         std::cout << "  void clockWiseCout(IntVec_t& m_16x1) \n  ";
         enum CWCout_Constraints : int {
            right = 1, noHorizontal = 0, left = -1,
            down  = 1, noVertical   = 0, up   = -1
         };

         // limits
         int minR =  0; // stop at 0 after 1 clockwise rotation
         int minC = -1; // stop at 0 - 1
         int maxR =  4; // stop at 3 + 1
         int maxC =  4; // stop at 3 + 1

         // focus
         int rr   = 0; // start upper left corner
         int cc   = 0;

         // start direction, top row, left col
         int rightOrLeft = right;       // horizontal  1, 0, -1
         int upOrDown    = noVertical;  // vertical    1, 0, -1

         // how many
         int count     = 4 * 4;

         do {
            // report current spot
            if(dbg) std::cout << "[" << rr << "][" << cc << "] ";
            std::cout << std::setw(2) << m_16x1 [ vecIndx(rr,cc) ] 
                      << "  " << std::flush;
            count -= 1;
            if(dbg) if(0 == (count % 8)) std::cout  << "\n  ";

            // move focus to next spot
            cc += rightOrLeft;  rr += upOrDown;

            // col limit check
            if((maxC == cc) && (right == rightOrLeft))
            {
               // right edge -> traveling right
               cc         -= rightOrLeft;    // back 1
               rightOrLeft = noHorizontal;   // no Horizontal move
               upOrDown    = down;           // down
               rr         += upOrDown;       // step
               maxC       -= 1;        // right edge completes, so back 1
            }
            else
               if((minC == cc) && (left == rightOrLeft))
               {
                  // left edge <- traveling left
                  cc         -= rightOrLeft;     // back 1
                  rightOrLeft = noHorizontal;    // stop Horizontal move
                  upOrDown    = up;              // up
                  rr         += upOrDown;        // step up
                  minC       += 1;    // left edge complete, so forward 1
               }
               else
                  // row limit check
                  if((maxR == rr) && (down == upOrDown))
                  {
                     // bottom -v traveling down
                     rr          -= upOrDown;      // back 1
                     upOrDown     = noVertical;    // stop vertical move
                     rightOrLeft  = left;          // left
                     cc          += rightOrLeft;   // step left
                     maxR        -= 1;    // bottom edge complete, back 1
                  }
                  else
                     if((minR == rr) && (up == upOrDown))
                     {
                        // top -^ traveling up
                        rr         -= upOrDown;     // back 1
                        upOrDown    = noVertical;   // stop vertical
                        rightOrLeft = right;        // right
                        cc         += rightOrLeft;  // step right
                        minR       += 1;            // top edge complete
                     }

         } while(count > 0);
         std::cout << std::endl;

      } // void clockWiseCout()


}; // class T496_t


int main(int /*argc*/, char** /*argv[]*/)
{
   Time_t start_us = HRClk_t::now();
   int retVal = -1;
   {
      T496_t   t496;
      retVal = t496.exec();
   }
   auto duration_us = 
      std::chrono::duration_cast<US_t>(HRClk_t::now() - start_us);

   std::cout << "\n\n  FINI   " << duration_us.count() << " us" 
             << std::endl;
   return(retVal);
}
```

With results (when dbg is false):

```
  Demo using int m_4x4[4][4]

  void show(int m_4x4[][4]) 
   1   2   3   4
   5   6   7   8
   9  10  11  12
  13  14  15  16

  void clockWiseCout(int m_4x4[][4]) 
   1   2   3   4   8  12  16  15  14  13   9   5   6   7  11  10  


  Demo using IntVec_t m_16x1

  void show(IntVec_t& m_16x1) 
   1   2   3   4
   5   6   7   8
   9  10  11  12
  13  14  15  16

  void clockWiseCout(IntVec_t& m_16x1) 
   1   2   3   4   8  12  16  15  14  13   9   5   6   7  11  10  


  FINI   364 us
```

- This code 'debugged' using gdb.

Comment: Note - the 'clock-wise circle' algorithm ends by counting how many values have been displayed, and ending when 16 counts down to 0 ... a simple and sufficient halting mechanism.  Yes, m_16x1.size() is 16.